# What is the difference between product of two functions and dot product of functions?

Tags: inner-products, orthogonality, products

Given two functions e.g.:
$$f(x)=\sin(x)
\text{, }
g(x)=2\cos(x)$$

Why can't we write:
$$f\cdot g=\sin(2x)$$

But we use this:
$$(f,g)=\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}f(x)g(x)dx$$
I don't quite understand if those two things are completely different and I'm mixing two totally different concepts.

Comment: The inner product should give a scalar value. Multiplying two functions gives you another function (element of your vector space).

Answer (score 2):

First operation maps two functions to a function, namely their product.

Second one maps two functions to a number.

So indeed very different operations.